# Where could we talk about doing a real live meet at an event? Is this the right forum?

Tags: support

I mentioned in another thread maybe hanging out at some race (Lemons!) and would like to know if its okay to talk about that here. I have no idea where else that could take place. Also, I don't want to come off as creepy and ask people for their email addresses. :)

Comment: That would be good. What part of the country are you in?

Comment: I'm on the south east coast. Could make an event in Florida or Georgia with no problem (have family there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the site is for what you are talking about as well as everything else.   Propose away!

Answer (score 0):

I would come to [the Mechanics chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop) to pitch the idea. From there you could also create a dedicated chat room to discuss and organise the meet-up.